# Get form field value after going back in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back-button

I have a contact form with a similar setup to the "Ask a question" form here on Stackoverflow, a user will click a suggested link that will take them away from the contact page, on the new page they get to there is a link back to the contact page via:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
```

When the user returns to the page the previously entered values (e.g. name, email, question, message) are filled in correctly. How can I access those values from JavaScript? (using jQuery)

```
element.val();
```

^ Returns nothing as technically as far as firebug tells me there's no value actually entered. The browser is somehow filling the fields. I only need to access one text field in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with jquery session. https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: This script to get the value $(selector).val(); selector is refer to id or class or element and etc for that particular text field.